# process.start always gives an error when looking opening a webpage

Tags: vb.net, process.start

This should be dead simple, but I'm pulling my hair out.  I simply want to open a web page from within a VB app.  Something like this:

```
Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Process.Start("https://www.bbc.com/news")
End Sub
```

But I always get this error:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'https://www.bbc.com/news' with working directory 'C:\xxx\BangOGram\BangOGram\bin\x64\Release\net6.0-windows'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

From what I can see from searching it appears to be an issue with the working directory but since I'm accessing a web browser that's universally available via the path I don't understand why.

I've tried setting the app to only work on x64 processor.

PS. Also tried:

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe","google.com")
```

Comment: If you target .NET5+ then you have to set the ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute property to True.

Comment: Hi Hans. Thank you so much... worked a treat.  Kind regards Jon